# AngularJS can't save to Database

Tags: php, angularjs

i've only recently started with Angular and I still have some difficulties...

I can't seem to update my database with my angular data, however i can get data from my database.

This is my code where I want to try and Post my data.

```
$scope.submit = function(infographic){
    var data = {
            id: infographic.PK_InfoID,
            label: infographic.label,
            value: infographic.value
        };
        console.log(data);
       $http.put("dataout.php", data).success(function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                                });
   };
```

And here is the PHP i use:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $label = $_POST['label'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $query = "UPDATE tblInfo SET label = '".$label"', value = '".$value"' WHERE PK_InfoID = '$id'";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Thx

Comment: Have you tried any debugging yourself? Have you checked if any data is sent to the server (with the web developer tools for you browser), do you see any javascript errors?

Answer (score 1):

Angular will send the request data as a json-encoded string. PHP will not be able to parse that string, thus `$_POST` is empty.

Use something like:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
  // use $data instead of $_POST
  print_r($data);
}
```

on the receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your PHP file:

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/postContents.txt', print_r($_POST, true));
```

That will tell you if your PHP script receives the data you expect.

Also: Make sure you're not creating SQL injection security issues. You should escape the values ($label, etc.). Google "sql injection php" for info.

Comment: Yes i know about the SQL injection issues but thats no problem, this is not going live...